# How Can You Update the Text In an NSTextField

Tags: cocoa

I am just starting out in xCode and I have built a very simple (mac, not iPhone) app that pops up a window with a text field, a label and a button.

I can get the app to pop up a message box with the string value of the text box, but I can't seem to set the string value of the text field with some default text.

The code I am using to try to populate the text field is:

```
[_txtBox setStringValue:@"Hello World"];
```

the set string method is the only method that looks like it should set the value of the box.  The program runs with no errors and when I click on the button, no error's are thrown.

If the text field contains text, the text displays in the label as it should.

If I place the line of code above just before the code that reads and outputs the text field, then instead of the text box showing that text box, the text box text just disappears as if I had over written the contents of the field with an empty string. The label is also blank.

Suggestionsn would be welcome; the almost identical expression I am using on the label works fine:

```
 [_lblOutPut setStringValue:_txtIP];
```

So I have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Cheers!

Dave

Comment: Show us "the code that reads and outputs the text field".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you are using "`NSTextField` with `NumberFormatter`" or "`NSTextField`".

"`NSTextField` with `NumberFormatter`" allows only numerals. If you try to set `NSString` it will display only an empty string.

Try this

```
[_txtBox setStringValue:@"123"];
```

Now, If you are getting 123 in your output, then definitely you are using "`NSTextField` with `NumberFormatter`"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you connected the right way the outlet in IB?
what's the output of

```
NSLog(@"%@", _txtBox);
```

(put it before the setStringValue)

Comment: I think that the textbox is defined correctly; as I said, I can read it's value into the label.  Everything was hooked up automatically in XCode rather than writing manual bits to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For text input, are you using a NSTextField or an NSTextView? They are vastly different in handling, `setStringValue:` works for NSTextField, yet NSTextView requires an attributed string to be passed to `[[textView textStorage] setAttributedString:...]`.

Comment: I am definitely using a Text Field.  Also, if I try putting the default text into a string and then try updating the label's text with that string, the label's text is blank rather than the value of the string.  I am defining the string with NSString *defVal = @"something".